# What does __real__ mean in C Preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I am not able to find out the definition for `__real__` in GNU C Preprocessor. Can anybody point me where i can find it ? I mean in which header file ? What is the significance of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with the preprocessor - `__real__` and `__imag__` are C99 language extensions for complex number support - see: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html

Note that these are non-standard extensions found in gcc and gcc-compatible compilers such as Intel's ICC.